# Amazon S3 + CloudFront Queries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently making a social sharing like app and I encounter a problem.

First off, S3 in my experience is slow, so I need to sync the data for multiple servers around the world to make it faster for multiple users.

So my question is, I need to create multiple buckets for each country right? Amazon has a list of their server locations. So for each user, I calculate the nearest server than upload there? How?

Next question, in my app people can subscribe to others and check for their updates. So realistically, this would not create a speed difference. If someone in Singapore uploaded a piece of text and has a subscriber in United States, it wouldn't be any quicker for this subscriber because he has to download a piece of text stored all the way in the Singapore.

All of this is making me confused! I personally find S3 very slow, which is why I am using CloudFront.

Any help? Am I misunderstanding the process? Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to iphone or objective-c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buckets are not per country, they are per region (EU, US, Asia, etc.)

Secondly, you do not have to manage closest URL to your S3 buckets, that's what CloudFront is for, you just get a single URL for each bucket and CloudFront will manage routing the user's request to the closest edge location.

PS: In addition, Amazon replicates data uploaded to your bucket across all edge locations transparently.

Comment: Could you answer my subscriber question please?

Comment: CloudFront means that if you have a bucket on S3, they will automatically replicate the contents of your bucket across all edge locations (data centers located around the world). So all you need to worry about is the URL to that CloudFront distribution. If I store text in Singapore, Amazon automatically replicates it in US, EU, etc.

So subscribers will definitely get a speed boost as long as you are using CloudFront.

Comment: Do you know how can I can get CloudFront and S3 setup together like this? Is there an API or some sort of console?

Comment: OK, I have figured out how to get CloudFront setup with S3, but how to do it in my app

Comment: Could you go ahead and check out my newest question?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon in no way "automatically" replicates your content out to the edge locations. Instead, your content is copied to a *single* edge location, if (and only) if the content is not there (could be the first pull, could be it's expired) when a user tries to access it from that edge. It is a pull mechanism, not a push. See "Download Distributions for HTTP Delivery" section of http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/